# Wordpress custom post types - 404

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, custom-post-type

I know a lot of people are going to down vote this but I'm going to ask anyways becuse it is a legit question and no other answers have helped. I'm going to first display the code and then ask.

```
<?php

    add_action('init', 'items_register');
    add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");
    add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

    function save_details(){
        global $post;
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "shelf_image", $_POST["shelf_image"]);
    }

    function items_register() {

        $__Test_items_labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Test items', 'post type general name'),
            'sinTestlar_name' => _x('item Item', 'post type sinTestlar name'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New item', 'item item'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New item Item'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit item Item'),
            'new_item' => __('New item Item'),
            'view_item' => __('View item Item'),
            'search_items' => __('Search items'),
            'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
        );

        $__Test_items_args = array(
            'labels' => $__Test_items_labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'our_items', 'with_front' => false ),
            'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=page',
            'capability_type' => array('page','post'),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','post_attributes')
          ); 

          $__Test_items_cat_labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Test items Categories', 'post type general name'),
            'sinTestlar_name' => _x('items Category Item', 'post type sinTestlar name'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New item Category', 'category item'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New item Category'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit item Category'),
            'new_item' => __('New item Category'),
            'view_item' => __('View item Category'),
            'search_items' => __('Search item Categories'),
            'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
        );

        $__Test_items_cat_args = array(
            'labels' => $__Test_items_cat_labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/cake.png',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'our_items', 'with_front' => false ),
            'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=page',
            'capability_type' => 'page',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','post_attributes')
        );  

        register_post_type( 'item' , $__Test_items_args );
        register_post_type( 'item_category' , $__Test_items_cat_args );
        flush_rewrite_rules( false );

    }

    function admin_init(){
        add_meta_box("item_parent_meta", "Test item Category", "item_catagory_parent", "item", "side", "low");
    }

    function item_catagory_parent(){
        global $post;
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'item_category', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        echo '<select name="parent_id" id="parent_id" style="width:100%;">';
        echo '  <option value="">(no parent)</option>';
        foreach( $loop->posts as $key => $obj ) {
            if( $obj->post_status === 'publish' )
                echo '<option ' . ( (int)$post->post_parent === (int)$obj->ID ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . ' class="level-0" value="' . $obj->ID . '">' . $obj->post_title . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }


?>
```

The reason I don't fully understand and need to ask this question is becuase it works in one instance, but not another.

The above registers 2 post types, one being a category, one being it's child.

for instance:

http://www.the-tack-shop.co.uk/our_items/dsfdfd/

Works

http://www.the-tack-shop.co.uk/our_items/dsfdfd/fggfdg/

returns a 404.

They both pretty much have the same arguments when registering the post type. You may also notice that I have added in a meta box which replicates the parent dropdown which does set the parent post correctly....

Does anyone know of why the second does not work? (please note flush_rewite_rule, goning to the permalinks page does not work).

Hope someone can help,

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can try to got to the permalink section and save it again! It worked for me